# How to detect that Spark stream processed all messages?

Tags: spark-streaming

At some point of time I know that no more messages are coming to the stream. How can I determine that all messages are processed by the Spark stream?

I want to use that information to (1) shut down the cluster, (2) to send a "job done" event to other parties.

Details:

- At the moment I don't count the incoming messages yet.
- A processed message results in a file in an S3 bucket.

Comment: Why don't you check if the last message was processed? Where are you storing the results? Guess you should save the count of the processed messages somewhere or request it from the app.

Comment: I use a distributed process to write messages to a queue. Thus there is no "naturally last message" in the current architecture. One could insert an additional step to identify the last message, sure. Is there a guarantee that all previous messages were processed when the last message was processed?

Comment: After some more thinking I think you should consider [StreamingQueryListener](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryListener).